# Parse date with groovy using spring boot

Tags: java, spring, groovy

I create a project with spring boot and groovy, 
I wanna parse a date but I dont understand why i got error.

For example i created a basic class for parse a Date

This is my class

```
class Test {
public static void main(String ...args){
    String oldDate = '04-DEC-2012'
    Date date = Date.parse( 'dd-MMM-yyyy', oldDate )
    String newDate = date.format( 'M-d-yyyy' )
}
}
```

I got the error,

```
Exception in thread "main" groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static java.util.Date.parse() is applicable for argument types: (String, String) values: [dd-MMM-yyyy, 04-DEC-2012]
Possible solutions: parse(java.lang.String), wait(), clone(), any(), grep(), use([Ljava.lang.Object;)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeStaticMissingMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1525)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeStaticMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1511)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaClassSite.call(StaticMetaClassSite.java:50)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:115)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:135)
```

My pom file is

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
        http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<groupId>com.xxx</groupId>
<artifactId>xxxxx</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>xxxxx</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-web -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-lang/commons-lang -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
        <artifactId>groovy</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-json-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
        <artifactId>groovy-json</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-rc-2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.groovy/http-builder -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
        <artifactId>http-builder</artifactId>
        <version>0.4.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--cliente rest -->
    <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mashape.unirest</groupId>
            <artifactId>unirest-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.9</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.gmavenplus</groupId>
            <artifactId>gmavenplus-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>addSources</goal>
                        <goal>addTestSources</goal>
                        <goal>generateStubs</goal>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <goal>generateTestStubs</goal>
                        <goal>compileTests</goal>
                        <goal>removeStubs</goal>
                        <goal>removeTestStubs</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Its possible that I need some extra configuration ? 
I read some post I only need Date.parse("format","date")
but for some reason I dont understand what i am doing wrong

Comment: try `mvn dependency:tree` to see if and which groovy is being brought into your build.

Comment: Please show the directory structure of the project and where your class is located. I think you just put your class into `src/main/java` directory instead of `src/main/groovy`.

Comment: Not your problem, but just a heads up: you have to change the groovy version with the spring bom with a property (https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-dependency-versions.html) and your attempt to get v3 for groovy-json is most likely futile

Comment: Hi, I test in this page [Online Groovy v2.4.8](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_groovy_online.php) , I dont have problem.  Running `mvn dependency:tree` **got**  `org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:jar:2.5.8:compile `. My class is on directory `src/main/groovy`

Answer (score 0):

Add the groovy date-util package

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-dateutil

Comment: With `mvn dependency:tree` got `org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:jar:2.5.8:compile` . So that I add dependenvy [groovy-dateutil 2.5.8](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-dateutil/2.5.8). The problem persist

Comment: I've tested by adding `groovy-dateutil` as well, and it works (And It should be :) ), may be the dependency has not been resolved correctly by the IDE. By the way it's not necessary to mention `groovy-dateutil` version in your pom, it will be inherited from Spring Boot.

Answer (score 0):

I change the version of groovy from 2.5.8 to 3.0.0-alpha-1 and the problem was resolved

So that I modified my pom.xml file

I delete this dependency

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

I add this line

```
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-alpha-1</version>
        </dependency>
```

I never had add the depency date-util .

Thanks to everyone for your support

[image]